# Use of macro before data type in C

Tags: c, function, macros

I wanted to know what is the use of a macro before any data types. I found many instances in the production code. But I don't understand the use of it. For Example:

```
#define OUT
#define IN

/* Function declaration is something like */

int my_func(IN const char *p, IN int d, OUT const char *x) {

    /* some normal operation */
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain me what is the purpose behind this?

Comment: It's basically a dumb, sloppy way to document functions, instead of writing proper, textual documentation inside the header file where that function is declared. Such documentation needs to address the use of all parameters.

Comment: `OUT const char *x` is complete nonsense, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way of documenting to the caller which parameters are input parameters, and which are output parameters. Though in your example case `x` can't be an output parameter since it's `const`, so it looks like `OUT` is being misapplied.

A more meaningful example would be:

```
struct server_t;

struct error_t {
    int32_t error_code;
    const char *message;
};

// Returns a new server instance on success. On error, fills the
// error with the error code and message (and returns NULL).
server_t *create_server(IN uint16_t port, OUT error_t *error);
```

In this example, `error` isn't really an input parameter. It doesn't change the behavior of the function. It's just a mechanism for the function to return some additional information to the user. As such, it gets labeled as `OUT`.

`port`, on the other hand, does change how the server is constructed and configured, so it's labeled as an `IN` parameter.

You could even have a parameter labeled as `IN OUT` if it is used as both an input and output parameter.

Comment: I got your point. So it's just a label. Thanks a lot @Cornstalks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define IN
#define OUT
```

wherever you use IN or OUT macro in program it will be replaced with nothing. in that function it is used before parameter type just for readability of the code. In most of the cases these kinda declaration is used for conditional compilation. observe this

```
int main(){
    IN int x;
}
```

after compiler preprocess phase your code will be

```
int main(){
    int x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @crook. I got it now.